# How to enable query store on the SSMS object browser with Sql Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016, query-store

I am following this guide: [Monitoring Performance By Using the Query Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817826.aspx#Enabling)

- I am using SSMS 2016 CTP3.2 and Sql Azure V12
- I have enabled the query store on the database properties.
- I can use the query performance insight on the azure portal.

But when I open the azure database on SMSS 2016 CTP3.2 and expand the database tree, the Query Store / Regressed Queries or any other options are available.

I want to be able to take the most IO consuming queries and analyze the execution plan.

Anything else I have to enable?

The relevant *is_query_store_on* column in *sys.databases* shows 0, but the database properties says it is enabled. I executed `ALTER DATABASE <DB> SET QUERY_STORE = ON;` but *is_query_store_on* still stays at 0.

The following query:

```
SELECT 
    actual_state, actual_state_desc, readonly_reason, 
    current_storage_size_mb, max_storage_size_mb
FROM sys.database_query_store_options;
```

Shows *actual_state* = 2;

Comment: Ok, so you *thought* you enabled it, but haven't. If the portal is showing it's enabled but `sys.databases` doesn't agree, contact support.

Answer (score 6):

This fixed my problem:

- Disabling the query store by command:

  ```
  ALTER DATABASE <DBNAME> SET QUERY_STORE = OFF;
  ```
- Then enabling it again fixed the problem.

  ```
  ALTER DATABASE <DBNAME> SET QUERY_STORE = ON;
  ```

Comment: Don't forget to set it back. It seems that QUERY_STORE = ON adds 3-5% performance impact.